# LMS aura subscribe to lwc

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning-web-components, aura, subscriber

LWC is publisher and aura subscriber to my lightning  message channel. It works good for only lwc, but for lwc to aura not. What is the problem?

LWC:

```
import { LightningElement, wire } from 'lwc';
import getAccounts from "@salesforce/apex/DataFetcher.getAccounts";

import { publish, MessageContext } from "lightning/messageService";
import TEST_MESSAGE_CHANNEL from "@salesforce/messageChannel/test_channel__c";

export default class LwcPublisher extends LightningElement {

    @wire(MessageContext)
    messageContext;
    
    @wire(getAccounts)
    accounts;

    selectedId;

    handleClick(event){
        console.log(event);
        console.log(event.target.dataset.id);
        this.selectedId = event.target.dataset.id; 

        const payload = { 
                            recordId: this.selectedId,
                            requestFrom: 'LWC' 
                        };

        publish(this.messageContext, TEST_MESSAGE_CHANNEL, payload);

    }

}
```

Aura

```
   <aura:attribute name="contacts" type="Contact[]" default="[]"/>
    <aura:attribute name="publishedId" type="String"/>
    <aura:attribute name="publishedFrom" type="String"/>

    <lightning:messageChannel
        aura:id="mchannel"
        type="test_channel__c"
        scope="APPLICATION"
        onMessage="{!c.handleMessage}"
    />

({
    handleMessage : function(component, message, helper) {
        if (message && message.getParam('recordId')){
            const accountId = message.getParam('recordId');
            
            component.set('v.publishedId', accountId);
            component.set('v.publishedFrom', message.getParam('requestFrom'));

            const apexAction = component.get('c.getContacts');

            // apexAction.setParams({accountId});
            apexAction.setParam('accountId', accountId);

            apexAction.setCallback(this, function(response){
                if(response.getState() === 'SUCCESS'){
                    component.set('v.contacts', response.getReturnValue());
                }
            });

            $A.enqueueAction(apexAction);
        } else {
            console.error('we got no message or message params');
            component.set('v.contacts', []);
        }
    }
})
```

Comment: Are you facing any error or exception, because the code looks fine, but not sure of the  components are deployed properly.

Comment: @NagendraSingh no error. Just nothing happens. Alert message return undefined even if hardcoded data.

Comment: Where did you put alert?

Comment: @NagendraSingh in handle message, Actually i tried and same code works good in another org, Idk whym but i think its closed. Thanks.